# Difference between RUM and UEM in Dynatrace

Tags: performance, web-application, performance-testing

I am New to this APM tool Dynatrace and was analyzing various offering of Dynatrace.
Can anyone please let tell me difference between Real User Monitoring (RUM) and User Experience Management (UEM) in Dynatrace?